# How Does Magento Pick Which Module File To Execute?

Tags: magento-1.9, module

Having a hard time understanding this.

I have a nested block like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="itemsShoes" module="MINE" template="slider/shoes.phtml"></block>
```

In my `local.xml`

The `MINE` module is defined in `app/etc/modules` and is in `magento/app/code/MINE` but I only have one PHP file in there.

My question is, as I add more php files how can I direct the block to pick which module PHP file it should execute?

Do I do this in `app/etc/modules`? So far it's just:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MINE>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>MINE</codePool>
        </MINE>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment due to less reputation. But if you have only php file at `magento/app/code/MINE` then your module is just register and its not doing anything. There should be `magento/app/code/MINE/moudle name/etc/config.xml`

which is the main file used to define block, model and controller as well as frontend and admin layout.

Hope it will help to understand more.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. Ftr it still worked I guess because it must make certain assumptions one just one file.